# Is Nginx running at all runlevels bad?

Tags: init.d, amazon-ami, chkconfig

I inherited some EC2 (running AMI) instances at my new job and I am trying to figure out the method that my predecessor used to set them up. This might be a really basic question, but my knowledge of the ins and outs of runlevels and init are poor so I want to confirm.

Based on this output nginx shouldn't be automatically started at any runlevel, right?

```
$ chkconfig | grep nginx
nginx           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

The nginx init script has this comment: `chkconfig - 85 15` which I believe means no runlevels also.

However according to this I believe that the server will actually run nginx at every run level, correct?

```
$ ls -1 /etc/rc.d/*/*nginx
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/K15nginx
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K15nginx
```

(All those K15nginx files are symlinks to ../init.d/nginx)

Is this something I should just fix (set some reasonable run levels), or is this working as intended and I should walk away (it ain't broke, don't fix it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's broke, fix it.

```
chkconfig nginx on
```

In your current configuration, nginx is never started automatically.

Note that the symlinks that start with `K` indicate that the service will be stopped (`k`illed) in that runlevel. Symlinks that start with `S` indicate that the service will be `s`tarted.